# Trying to return an image via MVC controller action after using ImageSharp resizing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, imagesharp

I am trying to take an image, resize it with ImageSharp via image.Mutate, save it to a stream, and return the image as a file via mvc controller to an Angular client. This is my code I am using to alter the image:

```
    public static MemoryStream ImageResizeStream(byte[] data, int maxHeight, int maxWidth, bool keepIfLower, string extension)
    {
        var size = new ImageSize();
        using (var image = Image.Load(data))
        {
            size.Height = image.Height;
            size.Width = image.Width;
        }

        ImageSize newSize = ScaleSize(size, maxWidth, maxHeight);

        var newStream = new MemoryStream();
        try
        {
            using (var image = Image.Load(data))
            {
                image.Mutate(x => x
                    .Resize(newSize.Width, newSize.Height));
                image.Save(newStream, GetImageEncoder(extension));
            }
            return newStream;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.Write(exception.Message);
        }

        return null;
    }
    public class ImageSize
    {
      public ImageSize()
      {

      }

      public ImageSize(int width, int height)
      {
          Width = width;
          Height = height;
      }
      public int Height { get; set; }
      public int Width { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is the controller action code that uses it:
(AlterImage is the class returning the stream)

```
    private FileStreamResult SetResult(SystemLogo logo)
    {
        var logoExtension = logo.FileName.Split('.').Last();

        var fileType = string.Empty;

        switch (logoExtension)
        {
            case "png":
                fileType = "image/png";
                break;
            case "jpg":
                fileType = "image/jpg";
                break;
            case "gif":
                fileType = "image/gif";
                break;
        }

        //var maxHeight = 38;
        //var maxWidth = 100;
        var newStream = AlterImage.ImageResizeStream(logo.Content, 38, 100, true, logoExtension);

        var result = File(newStream, fileType);
        return result;
    }
```

(I return this as the result of the action)

On the client, it is getting a 500 error that I have not been able to track as of yet. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: What line triggers the error? Have you configured your web site to return error details to help you diagnose the problem?

Comment: So, as of right now, I do not have any idea of where the error is being triggered. My site normally catches errors, but due to the way I am using the image, it bypasses the normal httpClient requests i use for everything else, and calls the api method directly as the url of the image.

Comment: I have set breakpoints throughout this code, but nothing actually gives me an exception inside the methods

Comment: So you've stepped through the code and it doesn't fail until after the return? Have you tried resetting the stream position to 0 and removed the `usings` to debug if a resource has been disposed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the stream position to 0 when passing a stream to a `FileResult`.

On top of that I can see some other issues (not related to your problem but not good either)

- You don't need the `ImageSize` class. There's already a `Size` struct in the `SixLabors.Primitives` namespace that is a property of the `Image<TPixel>` class.
- You're loading the image twice! You don't need to do that. Use the `Size` property inside the second `using` to calculate your new dimensions.
- You're calculating the mimetypes and choosing the encoder manually. `Image.Load` has an overload that gives you an `out IImageFormat` parameter. That contains an encoder, extension, plus the mimetype.

I'm curious about your `SystemLogo` class also. That the `Content` property is a `byte[]` strongly suggests to e you are using `ToArray()` somewhere when populating that object. If so, that's adding overhead you should try and avoid. Use streams to pass data instead.

Comment: Thanks! Setting the stream position to 0 did the trick. I appreciate the other tips as well! Made some changes to my code as a result.

Comment: Excellent, glad I was able to help.

Comment: Would be great if the final code was also updated.  I'm having a similar issue.